# In which language automation anywhere rpa tool developed

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I am working on automation anywhere tool. I want to know in which language they developed aa tool.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the "Automation Anywhere Client" in which you do development, that was written in .NET. The "Control Room" is a different story and it changed several times in the past few years / versions. It used to be a .NET desktop application, now it is a web application with Microsoft SQL Server as back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Automation anywhere  developed with  .NET and SQL backend
Control room is like web application to manage the automation anywhere client.where we can develop bots